# Создание сайта визитки на php

Tags: php

Решил создать сайт школы в формате сайта-визитки на чистом PHP. Столкнулся с тем, что для меня проблематично разбить эту задачу на подзадачи, т.е., банально, трудно понять с чего начать. Очевидно, что первоначально это должна быть верстка, но хотелось бы понять и более "локальные" задачи. Посоветуете какой то выход из этой ситуации?

Comment: Да чего сейчас понимать? Сейчас "сайты" в фотошопе делают, потом сверху кнопочек наложат где надо и всё, пипец, программисты.

Comment: А так, что вообще хочешь сделать? Если под "на чистом PHP" ты подразумеваешь именно язык программирования, то он серверный, ты ничего толком сделать не сможешь для сайта-визитки. html и css будет достаточно.

Comment: @Namous что за бред? Вы может так и делаете, но нормальные люди верстают по макету, а не накладывают кнопки на картинку. И вероятнее всего автор вопроса хочет создать динамический сайт, в котором будет меняться контент, раз он использует `PHP`.

Comment: Я бы предложил какой-то новостной блок и расписание, если новостной блок можно опустить, то вот расписание очень важный аспект и видеть максимально свежее расписание очень важно. Поэтому помимо вёрстки необходимо и сделать хранение и изменения данных. Всё зависит от того, что вы хотите видеть, а дальше уже можно раздробить задачи на составные и описать конкретно. Вы я так понял просите техническое задание, тогда стоит оформить подобающе, что вы в первую очередь хотите видеть на сайте и что должен получить конечный пользователь.

Answer (score 2):

Создание сайта-визитки можно разбить на следующие этапы:

1. Выписать на бумагу полное описание школы, что она из себя представляет, особенности, фишки, преимущества, контактные данные
2. Исходя из этого составить базовую структуру сайта в формате: Заголовок - текстовый блок с описанием
3. Разработать макет дизайна (я бы рекомендовал использовать figma - очень быстро разберётесь), графический контент, при отсутствии возможности его изготовить можно взять на стоках (например: unsplash.com и freepik.com)
4. По макету вам нужно выполнить html разметку, исходя из структуры разбить содержимое на блоки
5. Выполнить стилизацию CSS
6. Для сайта визитки бакэнд (а на php пишут именно бакенд как таковой не требуется), самое большое что вам может понадобиться это форма обратной связи, здесь у вас будет два варианта:

   - Вы можете отослать запрос через javascript на адрес простого php-скрипта, например param.php, передав нужные параметры
   - Вы можете вставить ваш html код внутрь файла index.php, форму обратной связи оформить через html-тег form и использовать обработку данных внутри index.php

Более конкретный алгоритм действий могу предложить только в случае более адекватного вопроса. Удачи!